# Disabling DirectWrite on Chrome messes things up, but I need to

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, font-smoothing

Disabling DirectWrite on Chrome (through chrome://flags), makes a number of websites display incorrectly and some not at all. But in all cases that the page is transformed, the elevator becomes tiny, in other words the page comes extremely tall all of a sudden.

But I need to purposefully necessarily disable DirectWrite for personal purposes, I want it to allow me to smooth font with [MacType](https://code.google.com/p/mactype/) font-smoothing software for Windows. Enabling it (DirectWrite), fixes everything, but it it does not allow for the fonts to be smoothed by the software I'm using.

So I need an intermediate solution, I want to disable DirectWrite, but I want websites to display correctly and smoothed by MacType. NOTE that this issue has started to happen since a week or so, it didn't exist before.

Chrome version is: 39.0.2171.95 (Official Build)

Comment: Why would you turn off a default feature in favour of a truly ancient and outdated render pipeline, for a library? Why not instead file an issue against the mactype lib going "your library doesn't work in windows, hopefully this is not too hard to fix, but the following things go wrong: ..." and then give them an explanation and some screenshots. Especially if this is happening for only a week, that's obviously a bug and you should be telling them about that first, instead of posting to stackoverflow

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You are so right actually. I can't believe I posted this on StackOverflow, I thought I posted on SuperUser, but never mind. It got fixed now! All of a sudden! I don't remember what I exactly did, but it did get fixed. If it helps anyone, here's what I remember doing: I restarted the machine, cleared Chrome's User Data (after backing them up), but the issue was still there, then after some time passed, I checked, and the issue was not there anymore! Miraculously! I hope I'd have more info so it would help someone else, but I don't. However, Thank God that it's fixed now!

Comment: wow, that sounds like a magical fix O_O good to hear it's no longer an issue though. Worth deleting the question from SO, I guess, then?